# Redirect user in php without revieling referer of page that redirected

Tags: redirect, referrer

How would I Redirect user in php without revieling referer of page that redirected

I figured I'd simply do something like this :: ( code example 2 ) ::
http://www.mustap.com/phpzone_post_62_how-to-bypass-the-referer-se

with the Get method , Simple example of what im trying to do is redirect to google without the referer of the php page I am referred from.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My cheesy fast solution:
If you check out [this form](http://anonym.to/en.html#singleLink) you'll see that you can forge a request to it's action doing the redirect you wish.

On the academic side, i can't think of a way to force a client not to send in the redirected request the *referrer* header (doing it without the middle anonymizer).